# Required: Method of moments fitting routine for the two-parameter generalized Pareto

Tags: extreme-value, pareto-distribution, method-of-moments

I am currently using the `evd` package which fits a two-parameter GPD by maximum likelihood.
Since in small samples the MOM is superior to the ML estimation I'd like to give it a go. However, the POT package - which could do the job - is offline due to memory access errors.

There are many extreme value packages around. However I am ONLY interested in the two-parameter GPD given by

$G(y)=  \begin{cases}  1-\left(1+ \frac{\xi y}{\beta} \right)^{-\frac{1}{\xi}} & \xi \neq 0 \\
1-\exp\left(-\frac{y}{\beta}\right) & \xi=0 \end{cases}$

or alternatively

$g(y)=  \begin{cases}  \frac{1}{\beta} \left( 1+\frac{\xi y}{\beta}      \right)^{-1-\frac{1}{\xi}} & \xi \neq 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\beta} \exp\left(-\frac{y}{\beta}   \right)    & \xi=0 
\end{cases}$

Is there any package that can fit such a distribution using a method of moments approach?

Comment: Do you have any reference or source for the statement "*in small samples the MOM is superior to the ML estimation*" in the case of the GPD? (It relates to another question here - one of mine, as it happens.)

Comment: See here: Hosking(1987) -- Parameter and Quantile Estimation for the Generalized Pareto Distribution. There seem to be quite a few typos in this paper though.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the Hosking and Wallis paper in Technometrics?

Comment: Jep, that's the one.

Comment: @Joz, can I ask what is the function that can be used for MLE estimation of GPD parameters in evd package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the case when $\xi = 0$ simply corresponds to an exponential distribution with scale parameter $\beta$, it is trivial to compute the method of moments estimator given $\overline y$, the first sample raw moment (the second is not needed since there is only one parameter to estimate in this case).  For the case $\xi < 1/2$ with $\xi \ne 0$, we can easily calculate $${\rm E}[Y] = \frac{\beta}{1-\xi}, \quad {\rm E}[Y^2] = \frac{2\beta^2}{(1-\xi)(1-2\xi)},$$ which shows that the first and second raw moments of $Y$ are defined only if $\xi < 1/2$.  Consequently, setting these to their respective sample moments and solving for the parameters easily yields the closed form solution $$\widehat{\beta} = \frac{\overline y \overline{y^2}}{2(\overline{y^2} - (\overline y)^2)}, \quad \widehat{\xi} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{(\overline y)^2}{2(\overline{y^2} - (\overline y)^2)},$$ where $\overline{y^2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2$ is the second sample raw moment.

Comment: (+1) The raw moments are defined even for negative values of $\xi$, not just $0\lt \xi\lt 1/2$, with the same solution.

Comment: Indeed, I was wondering why I had put that restriction in there when the equations didn't seem to need it.

Comment: It can be confusing because the PDF and CDF as given in the question are not quite correct: for $\xi\gt 0$ both are zero for $y\lt 0$ and for $\xi\lt 0$ they are supported only on the interval $[0, -\beta/\xi)$.

Comment: Unless $n$ is very small the results should be similar, since the usual (i.e. Bessel corrected) sample variance and $\overline{y^2} - (\overline y)^2$ are the same up to a factor of $\frac{n-1}{n}$.